# call javascript from updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using google charts to draw a set of charts changing chart type with a dropdownlist.

however, after wrapping the dropdownlist in an updatepanel, the javascript is no longer being fired. first line in javascript is an alert to confirm.

the code that's supposed to fire the javascript:

```
protected void Unnamed_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    if (ddl.SelectedItem != null) {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        string script = String.Format("drawChart(\'{0}\',\'{1}\',\'{2}\',\'{3}\',\'{4}\');", chart.ClientID, ddl.SelectedValue.ToString(), "i en kage i gram", "string,NOGETTEKST;number,Mængde", "Mel,500;Sukker,500;Smør,100;Salt,32;Vand,400;Cola,150");
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "isActive", script, true);
    }
}
```

this worked fine before i put the updatepanel around the dropdownlist.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="hejbamse" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ddl" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="LineChart" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="PieChart" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="BarChart" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="ColumnChart" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" runat="server"></div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

i've tried different approaches using scriptmanager instead of clientscript inspired from different answers on SO, but with no luck.

EDIT:

replacing:

```
cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "isActive", script, true);
```

with:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatepanelid, updatepanelid.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
```

fixied it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try put the script in a Literal, instead of

```
cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "isActive", script, true);
```

PS. I haven't test it.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ?

Comment: You can the text of a Literal control to be a script and it will execute it. For example:
ltrlControl.Text = "<script>alert(\"alabala\");</script>";

Comment: do you mean putting the entire javascript in the `script` instead of just the function call?

Comment: I meaned to change this line: 
`cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "isActive", script, true);` to:
`ltrlControl.Text = script;`

Comment: tried this, with just the alert. The alert is fired when there's no update panel, but when it is inserted inside the updatepanel nothing happens, as with my original attempt.

Comment: `LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(); lc.Text = "<script>alert(\"alabala\");</script>"; chart.Controls.Add(lc);//an empty div`

Comment: using scriptmanager instead of clientscriptmanager made it work. Thanks for helping.